# Get Weather Reports from the Command Line

Tags: terminal, command-line, weather.app

Just for my curiosity and knowledge, do you know if it is possible by using the **Terminal Command Line** to check my current weather conditions only by using the native **Apple Framework**?

I am aware of some specific command line that I can execute in my Terminal such as `finger montreal@graph.no` or `curl wttr.in/melbourne`

but I am more interesting if I can use some kind of utility that comes by default within the official Apple framework and only use the Terminal Shell.

I noticed that Apple has two directories:

```
PrivateFrameworks/WeatherKit.framework/

PrivateFrameworks/WeatherFoundation.framework/
```

Comment: A few years ago I used [Dark Sky](https://darksky.net/forecast/40.7127,-74.0059/us12/en) to build a Twitter application that provided weather forecasts for my "followers". Dark Sky was free, amazingly functional and I was able to generate my forecasts easily from JSON data with a `bash` script. Sadly, Apple bought it, and it's effectively dead AFAIC. However, there are some providers that claim to be ["Dark Sky replacements"](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=replacement+api+for+dark+sky&t=ffab&atb=v278-1&ia=web) - you may find something useful.

Comment: Yes it's possible, I found https://github.com/zadr/Weather/tree/0ebe3c05d54d36913a4aef19da46b9ee76e3b595 which shows an example of how to interact with the private weatherkit framework. Just wrap that in a CLI app and your'e good to go

Answer (score 2):

Yes it's possible to call into the weatherkit framework. The key method in question is `currentDailyForecastForCoordinate`. You can see a full example of how to use this in practice (as well as other methods that are available) in this [repo](https://github.com/zadr/Weather) (not mine), but essentially once you obtain the header file (e.g. via classump) for WeatherKit you can just call into the library via something like

```
    [[WMWeatherStore sharedWeatherStore] currentConditionsForCoordinate:location.coordinate result:^(WMWeatherData *result) {
        // Do something with result
    }];
```